# Eclipse not importing android project

Tags: android, eclipse

When i go Android->Existing Android Code into workspace then it just doesn't do anything.The next button doesn't highlight.Help me please.Ive screenshot-ted the problem>
Currently using Eclipse Photon June update

[image]

Comment: you need to select appropriate project directory/jar.

Comment: @mr.roshan I didn't get what you said.